# Partially copy a folder, preserving the invisible system files contained, but only some of the remaining content

Tags: macos, finder, filesystem, copy-paste, invisible-files

I am looking for a way to copy a folder, with all the invisible and system files it contains in its "first level", but only some of the other visible, "normal" folders it contains?
This is related to a "Time Machine" data transfer, from an old disk to a new one. But I think it is a question interesting in its own.

Comment: You could do this with rsync and it's --include and --exclude options.

Answer (score 2):

First create a new folder where you will copy the data to: `mkdir <dest_folder>`. Then use:

```
# "First level" hidden files
find <source_folder> -d 1 -name ".*" -print0 | xargs -0 -J % cp -R % <dest_folder>
# Normal folders
cp -R <source_folder>/<folder1> <source_folder>/<folder2> ... <dest_folder>
```

Comment: `cp -r <source_folder>/.*` can cause the current working directory to be copied to the destination. Much safer to `shopt -s dotglob; cp <source_folder>/* <dest_folder>`. Then a second copy with the `-R` option for any folders.

Comment: Interesting. In fact, it will even include `<source_folder>/..`. I didn't notice since i use `zsh`, which will not include `.` and `..`. However, your suggestion will not copy any hidden directories until you explicitly pass them to the second `cp -R`. It will also copy possibly unwanted non-hidden files in the source directory.